# Why is the reduce function producing a result in reverse order?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement a map function through the reduce function. I am following the sample code that Rich Hickey had written in the presentation he had given on transducers.

```
(defn mapr [f coll] (reduce (fn [xs x] (cons (f x) xs)) () coll))

(println (mapr inc '(1 2 3 4 5))) ; (6 5 4 3 2)
```

However I'm failing to understand why the list is getting mapped in reverse order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `cons` puts the item to the front of a seq. See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cons:

```
(cons x seq)
```

> Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
>     the rest.

So in your case `1` will be incremented to `2`, then put to the beginning of an empty list, giving `'(2)`. The next value to be processed by the reducing function is `2`. It will be incremented to `3` then placed at the beginning of `'(2)`, giving `'(3 2)`, and so on...

Note that my language is a little *loose*: each time the reduce function is called a new seq is returned i.e. `cons` creates a new list each time it is called.

Comment: Agreed, however reduce is performed from left to right, right ? In that case it should result in `(f(x), ...)`. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Utsav The reduce does proceed from left to right, but think of it this way: the next element is always put in front (left) of the current one. So, this reduce implements a `reverse` operation. I hate to admit, but this confused me as well.

Comment: Ahh got it. However doing a conj `(defn mapr [f coll] (reduce (fn [xs x] (conj xs (f x))) () coll))` is also yielding the same result.

Comment: For comparison start with `[]` and use `conj`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/520209/utsav](@Utsav) BTW, the reason the example is written with an implicit reverse, I think, is because `cons` requires a seq, and the first parameter is not expanded. So, `(cons xs (f x))` would not work for both reasons, and the example code would be much more complicated.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy it worked !! Why didn't `conj` work when I passed an empty list as the initial value ?

Comment: @Utsav `conj` adds to different place, depending on the type of collection. It adds to the begin of a list, and to the end of a vector.

Comment: @ToniVanhala Thanks !